# Changing color to one element of blogger title

Tags: css, colors, blogger

I'm trying to further customize my blog title.  Here is my current blog title:

```
Savannah's ❊ Secretaire
```

How do I change the middle symbol's color to #b32c20?  I want the words to remain black.  It would be awesome if there was a CSS code I could add.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot change the HTML you can use gradient to color your text and you will be able to apply a specific color to the symbol.

```css
h1 {
  display:inline-block;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, black 48%,#b32c20 48%, #b32c20 60%,black 50%);
  background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<h1>Savannah's ❊ Secretaire</h1>
```

*The values of the gradient aren't generic and will depend on the text*

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add a span around the middle symbol, like this:

```
Savannah's <span class="title-symbol">❊</span> Secretaire
```

and then target that span with CSS like this:

```
.title-symbol {
     color: red; // put whatever color you want here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color of the symbol by using a span element to apply specific attributes to an element.

**HTML:** `<h1>Savannah's <span class="class">❊</span> Secretaire</h1>`

**CSS:** `.class { color: #b32c20 }`